# Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void includes(String) from the type String

Tags: apex, compile-error

I've been receiving this error and need some help resolving it.

```
for(LP_TFL__c tfl : termForLoanList0)
{

    for(ScorecardTier scorecardTier : scorecardTierList0)
    {

      //Compare Tiers String on Term Object to Scorecard Tier Name and Match 
      //Credit Line Values Accordingly 


       *if(tfl.Tiers__c.includes(scorecardTier.tierName))
       {
            ScorecardTier.creditLine = tfl.Credit_Line_Max_Amt__c;
            ScorecardTier.promoDays = tfl.Promotional_Period__c;
            ScorecardTier.apr = tfl.Interest_Rate__c;
       }

     }
}
```

> Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void includes(String)` from the type String

The loop is supposed to compare all tiers in termForLoans and add the matching attributes to scorecardTier object when it finds a match in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right function to use here is `contains()`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm):

> contains(substring)
>
> Returns true if and only if the String that called the method contains the specified sequence of characters in substring.
>
> Signature
>
> public Boolean contains(String substring)
>
> Parameters
>   substring
>
> Type: String
>
> Return Value
>   Type: Boolean
>
> Example
>
> ```
> String myString1 = 'abcde';
> String myString2 = 'abcd';
> Boolean result = myString1.contains(myString2);
>
> System.assertEquals(result, true);
> ```